# What is the meaning of the following code?

Tags: c

Could anyone tell me what is the meaning of the following code :

```
unsigned char  const *display_screen[] = {
    "\xfeXEPC Main Menu:\n\35System Status\n System Settings\n Access Control",    
    "\xfeXEPC Main Menu:\n System Status \n\35System Settings\n Access Control",
    "\xfeXEPC Main Menu:\n System Status \n System Settings\n\35Access Control",
    "\xfeXEPC Main Menu:\n\35Configuration\n Op.Programming\n Event Log  ",
    "\xfeXEPC Main Menu:\n Configuration\n\35Op.Programming\n Event Log  ",
    "\xfeXEPC Main Menu:\n Configuration\n Op.Programming\n\35Event Log  ",
    "\xfeXEPC Main Menu:\n\35History    ",
    "\xfeXEPC Main Menu:\n"};
```

Comment: Seems like it's setting up a command line menu.

Comment: you should "format" your code. That makes it more viewable, and more likely for people to respond to your question.

Comment: It's an array of pointers to string literals.  The escapes in the string probably have meaning to some larger piece of software (they aren't standard), so more context is needed.

Answer (score 3):

The code is invalid.  The string literals are of type `char[N]` (where `N` is the length of each string literal).  These are implicitly convertible to `char*` but not to `unsigned char*`.  Since the code is invalid, it doesn't have any meaning.  :-)

If `display_screen` was a `const char*[]` instead of a `const unsigned char*[]`, this would declare `display_screen` as an array of `const char*` with the pointers in the array pointing to the string literals listed in the initializer.

Comment: I noticed the `signed` / `unsigned` issue but didn't remark on it because my brain is off today. +1

Comment: This answer strikes me as somewhat silly since this isn't what the OP is after, and besides the code compiles with signedness warnings on at least two compilers I have at hand.

Comment: @ergosys:  Comeau doesn't accept it in either C89 or C99 mode.  I don't know what else the OP could be after.  If he wants to know what this code is for, no one here can tell him.  He needs to go look where he found it.

Comment: Gcc -Wall, clang -Wall, and The on-line comeau compiler in "relaxed" mode generate only warnings.  Actually Comeau didn't produce any warnings at all.

Comment: @ergosys:  Why would you ever want to use "relaxed" mode?

Comment: @James, to fix crappy gcc/clang code that has never seen -Wall?

Comment: @ergosys:  Right.  What I meant was "why would you ever want to use "relaxed" mode when checking whether some code is valid or not?"

Comment: @James: string literals are not `const char` arrays, but unfortunately only `char`, but where you don't have the right to modify the contents.

Comment: @Jens:  Oh, thanks.  In C++ they are arrays of `const char` and there is a deprecated implicit conversion to `char*`.  I didn't realize C was different.  Good to know!

Answer (score 0):

Besides the signedness issue that James mentions, this defines an array of strings. The `"\xfe"` at the beginning translate to hexadecimal value `0xfe` and the `"\35"` translates to octal `035`. The interpretation of these values is dependent of your platform.